# What Does [end=""] means python?

Tags: python, python-3.x

So I have been solving this problem on HackerRank and got stuck thinking about how to print the output of the problem on the same line. After that, I gave up and looked up the answer on the internet. Even though it worked all confused about how and why.

https://www.hackerrank.com/challenges/python-print/problem?isFullScreen=true

here is the Link of the Problem

I did reach this point and got stuck:

```
n = int(input())
for i in range(1, n+1):
    print(i)
```

The output should be 123...n.

My Output was
1
2
3
.
.
.
n(every number on a new line)

The output should be in the same line.
So here is the required soln to the problem

```
n = int(input())
for i in range(1, n+1):
    print(i, end="")
```

Can Anyone explain how it works? How did this `, end=""` changed the whole solution

Comment: Read the documentation please. Or use an IDE that will show the actual doc strings whne you hover over the thing you're using. https://docs.python.org/3/library/functions.html#print the very first line explains it: "Print objects to the text stream file, separated by `sep` and followed by `end`. `sep`, `end`, `file`, and `flush`, if present, must be given as keyword arguments." Please do not use StackOverflow as a substitute for very basic web searches, or for the official documentation

Comment: That is a keyword argument being passed to the `print` function.

Comment: @CasperKuethe StackOverflow wouldn't be as popular in search engine rankings as it is today if it didn't take an aggressive stance on low quality posts. Nothing I said was mean, it's just not sugarcoated. ETA: besides, someone's experience as a programmer has no impact on whether they can follow rules, be polite, make sure they're following guidelines, etc.

Comment: google: "python print without newline" => https://stackoverflow.com/questions/493386/how-to-print-without-a-newline-or-space

Comment: @CasperKuethe I was helpful though, I provided all the info that was needed.

Comment: @maddes8cht this post specifically will not show up because it's a duplicate of a much more popular one; if something has an existing answer, watering down the site with duplicate posts with lower-quality answers is not the solution to help the site's SEO rankings.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

python adds a `'\n'` (newline) character after each string if you use the print function. With the named argument `end` you can provide a custom last character, or a string, instead of `'\n'`. So if `end=""` there will be nothing added to the end resulting in everything printed on the same line.

Answer (score 1):

#### It means do not start a new line at the end of the `print`

By default, Python puts a newline character at the end of a print statement.

If you want, instead, to keep the output cursor on the same line, so you can print something afterwards, use `end=""`. The next print statement will continue outputting on the same line.

```
print("Hello, ")
print("World!")
```

gives you

```
Hello,
World!
```

But

```
print("Hello, ", end="")
print("World!")
```

gives you

```
Hello, World!
```

Here is my evidence.

[image]

Comment: Its meaning is more general than you imply. The value of the `end` parameter is just the string that gets prints after all the arguments. Its *default* value happens to be `'\n'`. Changing it implies that no new line is started *only* if the new value doesn't contain a `\n'`.